# Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: Connect Failed

Tags: networking, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

```
Prog:dist abhishek$ composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString
```

Deploying business network from archive: my-network.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: my-network@0.1.6
    Description: My Commodity Trading network

✖ Deploying business network definition. This may take a minute...

> Error: Error trying deploy. Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: Connect Failed
>   Command failed

***when trying to install the composer runtime,returns***

```
Prog:dist abhishek$ composer runtime install -n my-network -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString
```

✖ Installing runtime for business network my-network. This may take a minute...

> Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: Connect Failed
>   Command failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Fabric running? What is the output of `docker ps`?

Comment: Thanks.docker is having trouble
`docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Proxy Authentication Required.`

Comment: Hey Dan, Tried to do docker right but still same problem persists....Help with this.

`Prog:dist abhishek$ composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString`
..
Error: Error trying deploy. Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: Connect Failed
Command failed

Comment: Seems like your docker install is broken somehow. What operating system? Are you running the latest Docker?

Comment: Running on macOS High sierra this: Version 17.09.0-ce-mac33 (19543)
Channel: stable     e2f2204fde. I am in a proxy network.

Comment: Deploying business network from archive: my-network.bna
Business network definition:
 Identifier: my-network@0.1.6
 Description: My Commodity Trading network
E1007 21:37:48.074015000 140735631831872 http_proxy.c:64]              userinfo not supported in proxy URI
E1007 21:37:48.074777000 140735631831872 http_proxy.c:64]              userinfo not supported in proxy URI
E1007 21:37:48.332683000 140735631831872 http_proxy.c:64]              userinfo not supported in proxy URI
Error trying deploy.Error trying install composer runtime. Error: Connect FailedCommand failed

Answer (score 2):

I've been working through the Hyperledger Composer tutorial (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html) on an older Mac, running OS X Mavericks 10.9.5, which means I'm using Docker Toolbox instead of Docker for Mac. I encountered the same error message when deploying the sample Trading network .bna file on my local dev environment Fabric network.

Here is the command in Terminal:

```
$ composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString -A admin -S
```

And here is the error log:

> Error: Error trying deploy. Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: Connect Failed

In my case, it was because Docker Toolkit answers to on an IP address assigned when you start docker, instead of localhost, 127.0.0.1, etc.

If you are also using Docker Toolkit and are getting the same error, first find the docker IP number, which should be listed under the Docker Whale logo in Terminal when you started it, and then edit the following files (TextEdit should be fine), changing all references to `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` to the IP number (leave the ports, such as `:7050`, there):

- fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/configtx.yaml
- fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/docker-compose.yml
- fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/createComposerProfile.sh
- fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/createPeerAdminCard.sh

Then, back in Terminal, navigate back to fabric-tools, and if Fabric is already started, stop it, and then recreate the Composer Profile, as documented:

```
$ ./stopFabric.sh
$ ./createComposerProfile.sh
```

The log should now show the Docker Toolkit IP for the orderers, CA and peers. Now restart Fabric:

```
$ ./startFabric.sh
```

Navigate back to `fabric-tools/my-network/dist` and re-run the compose command, and if all goes well, it should connect properly.

Comment: Switching from Docker ToolBox to Docker for Mac worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the next:
Pick a directory that you want and install Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperledger Composer Playground running:

```
curl -sSL https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/install-hlfv1.sh | bash
```

Then run your command.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
$composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n basic
$composer network deploy -a basic.bna -A admin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -f admincard
```