# Hyperledger Composer not being able to deploy Business Network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I updated my local environment to Composer v0.14.3 and I have been following the [Developer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html) from Hyperledger Composer website. Then, when I try to deploy the Business Network to local Hyperledger Fabric I am getting the following error under the section "Deploy to the running Hyperledger Fabric". The error I get is shown below:

```
Deploying business network from archive: my-network.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: my-network@0.0.1
    Description: My Commodity Trading network

✖ Deploying business network definition. This may take a minute...

Error: Error trying deploy. Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: Endpoint read failed
Command failed
```

Another issue I saw is that I am able to start the local Hyperledger Fabric via "startFabric.sh" script, but after several minutes the container "hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.4" stops suddenly, so I have to run the "stopFabric.sh" and "startFabric.sh" scripts again, [see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxAWB.png).

As a reference, I have done what is suggested on this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511988/error-error-trying-install-composer-runtime-error-connect-failed), but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: hello, what OS and which version? One thing: you say you have done `stopFabric.sh` and then `startFabric.sh`  ; you will need to run `./createComposerProfile.sh` in the same `fabric-tools` directory as the next step - because there will be a new CA docker container when you 'startFabric' all over again.  In the next release 0.15.0, you will create a Composer PeerAdmin card for the dev environment.

Comment: The software I am using is the following:

Hyperledger Composer 0.14.3
Node 6.12.0
npm 3.10.10
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
docker-compose version 1.14.0-rc1, build c18a7ad

According to Hyperledger documentation, I think Step 2 says that ./createComposerProfile.sh script must be run once at the first time the Fabric is started, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to update (ie re-install) your Composer dev environment to the current release v0.15.0 (as of Nov 10th) - there is a new tutorial (its changed from what you saw) and it will use Business network cards for the network deploy (createComposerProfile.sh is no longer needed) - makes life easier.  To get the latest version, you will need to install the modules as per the docs -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html - this will get the latest release. Make sure you do a full teardown using the scripts you downloaded in fabric-tools (as your CC containers will be 0.14.3 or earlier and thus out of date) and that you then subsequently, do an npm -g uninstall of the same module names eg composer-cli, composer-playground etc and such that they are all at the same level (0.15.0) upon subsequent npm -g install of same composer modules.

Comment: I have updated my environment and I did the tutorial again, everything seems to work correctly. It is important to mention that today I had available an update from Docker, so it may be associated with the fix to my issue

Comment: cool..your Docker version (as you originally posted) should be OK regardless. Just to write also (my comment on business network cards) is that the Composer Dev environment setup script `createComposerProfile.sh` (since v0.15.0) is effectively replaced by `createPeerAdminCard.sh` as cards are now being used, just FYI.